Create custom array object type with additonal functions and class declaration?
Iam struggling with creating an custom array object type with additional functions, and a class construtor:
The custom array object should have the following content:
["fruits", ["apple", "banana", "pineapple"]]; //array content: string and another array


I would like to work on such an array with custom functions, like:

Array.prototype.returnArrayContent = function(){
    this[1].forEach(element => console.log(element)); }
// But the problem in this case is I add another function to the array prototype, instead 
// I would like to a new Object type which inherits all functions, property from built-in-Array-Object


Because I read in data from JSON file I would like to create those custom array objects with a class constructor like:

new customArrayObject (["fruits", ["apple", "banana", "pineapple"]])

How could this be achieved? As Iam kind of a newbie do I need typescript for this?

What should happen if you call push or pop on such an array? Which method would give access to the "fruits" value and possibly change it? What if someone adds another string after "fruits"? This question needs more clarification and specification of what exactly the desired interface is and how it should work for all those methods.

Thanks, for your contribution. I will specify my simplified question, the custom array object is part of a bigger structure, give me a while for updating...

I wouldn't use the constructor to init the array since the native constructor just adds 1 element in the case. Having the custom array behave differently could be confusing. Just create some fill function and fill the custom array recursively. You could reuse it in the constructor also to match the native constructor:


class MyArray extends Array{
  constructor(...items){
    if(typeof items[0] === 'number' && items.length === 1){
      return super(...items);
    }
    super();
    this.fill(items);
  }
  fill(arr){
    for(const item of arr){
      if(Array.isArray(item)){
        this.push(new MyArray().fill(item));
        continue;
      }
      this.push(item);
    }
    return this;
  }
}


const arr = new MyArray(...["fruits", ["apple", "banana", "pineapple"]])
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
const deleted = arr.splice(0,1);
console.log(deleted.constructor.name);
console.log(arr[0].constructor.name)
arr[0].fill(['some more fruits', ['mango', 'melon']]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));




Brilliant, thanks for your valueable answer!

@KeepRunning85 i've updated the answer with the constructor accepting your data
